# Why React not accept environment variable set in Heroku?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, create-react-app

I am following docs here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

did set up in heroku the variable:

REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT = prod

and checking in code:

```
export const fbAppId =
  process.env.REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT === "prod"
    ? "316459592894290"
    : "1162568760820386";
```

But somehow always the NOT "prod" version is assinged. Do you have any idea why?

I have react-script 3.4.3.

Comment: Could it be one of those triple equal to vs double equal to scenarios.. ? What machine are you on btw?

Comment: I have a Mac. Why not `===`? I guess both value are string.

Comment: I'm not sure how Heroku is interpreting the environment variables, but `===` would do a strict equality comparison.. So if Heroku is not reading the "prod" as a string, the condition will fail. Can you try with `==`, and share the result ?

Comment: You could also, change the env variables on Heroku instead of using double equal to, 
`heroku config:set REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT = "prod"`

Comment: I think the solution was not only reload dyno, but make a very new relese.

Comment: Your React app **does not** have access to the environment variables on the server, it's running in your users' browsers. Those prefixed env vars are exposed via Webpack at _build_ time, as the linked docs clearly highlight, so you can't just set the variable or even restart the dyno, because the same compiled slug is used. Generally I think this kind of build time config is better avoided for reasons I expand on in https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html.